# Gallery images are starting from center of gallery in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

[image]

I am having a gallery in between two buttons as seen below in my xml file. In the Gallery, images are adding from the centre.

```
<RelativeLayout
      android:layout_height="80dp"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:id="@+id/gal"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:background="@drawable/backgroundblackwhite">
       <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:background="@drawable/backward"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
       <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:background="@drawable/forward"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
      <Gallery 
          android:layout_height="100dp"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:id="@+id/gallary"
          android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
          android:spacing="5dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
          android:background="@drawable/greypattren"/>  
   </RelativeLayout>

I want the images to start from Left of my Gallery. I used the below code to set the gallery images to start from the left of gallery view.
```

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

```
            Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);

            // set gallery to left side
            MarginLayoutParams mlp = (MarginLayoutParams) g.getLayoutParams();
            mlp.setMargins(-(metrics.widthPixels / 2 + (imageWidth/2)), mlp.topMargin,
                        mlp.rightMargin, mlp.bottomMargin);
```

But, my Gallery is going to the extreme left i.e hiding my Button in the left(which I should use for scrolling Gallery)

I am posting the Screenshots of both the images,
1)The Gallery View which I want, and I want the images to add from the left of the screen.
2)Changing of the Gallery after adding the above code(setting the margins) using metrics.

Did I need to change anything in xml or code?

please help
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Hi Do you got Answer?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 MarginLayoutParams mlp = (MarginLayoutParams) g.getLayoutParams();
 mlp.setMargins(-(metrics.widthPixels / 2 + (imageWidth/2)), mlp.topMargin,
 mlp.rightMargin, mlp.bottomMargin);
```

To

```
mlp.setMargins((int) -(metrics.widthPixels/2.5), mlp.topMargin, mlp.rightMargin,                    mlp.bottomMargin);
```